# Consultar os nomes dos pilotos patrocinados por uma Equipe

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Quero consultar pilotos patrocinados pela equipe 'A'

Estou fazendo assim:

```
SELECT piloto.nome AS NomePiloto
FROM equipe
INNER JOIN piloto
ON equipe.idequipe = piloto.idequipe
INNER JOIN patrocinador
ON patrocinador.idpat = equipe.idpat
WHERE patrocinador.nome = 'A'
```

Mas, não está retornando nada, onde estou errando?

O modelo é este:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: qual o erro que retorna? o `idpat`, `idequipe` e `nome` estão realmente escritos assim no banco? na imagem que você apresentou, estão como `ID_PAT`, `NOME_E` e `NOME_P`.

Comment: Nas ligações para estar tudo OK, mas o problema poderá estar nos dados. Tem a certeza que tem pilotos associados a equipas e equipas patrocinadas com o nome "A"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você quer os nomes dos pilotos, melhor usar como tabela principal a `pilotos`, assim facilita montar a *query*.

```
SELECT pi.nome as piloto, eq.nome_e as equipe, pt.nome_p as patrocinador
FROM piloto pi
LEFT JOIN equipe eq ON eq.id_equipe = pi.id_equipe
LEFT JOIN patrocinador pt ON pt.id_pat = eq.id_pat
WHERE pt.nome_p LIKE 'A%'
```

Usei o `LIKE` assim trará todos que começam com a letra `A`.